# Get image and insert into another div using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to grab the image of the first `swiper-slide` to insert into the div with a class of  `tt1`?

Only image of first `.swiper-slide`!

Ex:

```
<div class="tt1"></div>    
<div class="ss1">...</div>
<div class="ee1">
    <div class="ee2">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image2.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

```
<div class="tt1"><img src="/image1.jpg"></div>    
<div class="ss1">...</div>
<div class="ee1">
    <div class="ee2">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image2.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or I could take the first image to form the background?

```
<div class="tt1" style="background: url(/image1.jpg);"></div>    
<div class="ss1">...</div>
<div class="ee1">
    <div class="ee2">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image2.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$('.swiper-slide:eq(1) img').clone().appendTo('div.tt1')`

```html
<div class="tt1"></div>    
<div class="ss1">...</div>
<div class="ee1">
    <div class="ee2">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image2.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $('.swiper-slide:eq(1) img').clone().appendTo('div.tt1')
   $('.tt1 img').removeAttr('style');
</script>
```

Comment: How's this any different from the answer I posted?

Comment: You are using `.swiper-slide:first` and i am using `.swiper-slide:eq(1)`. Different ways of selectors is there may be these simple differece will help you to some one. `eq(2),eq(3)` also we can use for next elements.

Comment: You can remove style of image ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116225/discussion-between-mani-and-le-tung).

Comment: `:eq(1)` is the same as `:first` so your answer is the same

Comment: Yes both are same but, `eq(2),eq(3)` also we can use, we cannot use `:second,:thrid` like that.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
$('.swiper-slide:first img').clone().appendTo('div.tt1')
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jk80c74s/)**

This selects the first element of the class swiper-slide, then the image, copies it and appends it to the div with class tt1. The resulting HTML is:

```
<div class="tt1"><img src="/image1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;"></div>    
<div class="ss1">...</div>
<div class="ee1">
    <div class="ee2">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image2.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.tt1').append($('.swiper-slide:first-child img').clone())
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

To achieve this you will use a CSS selector to target your first image, which will later be used as your jQuery selector.

You'll need to use the pseudo-class `:first-child`, later on create a clone using `clone()` jQuery method and finally appending that clone to the desired `div` element using the `appendTo()` method.

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/gykLgjm8/)

---

*Image being cloned surrounded in red. Image cloned and appended surrounded  in blue.*

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
$(".swiper-slide:first-child img").clone().appendTo($(".tt1"));
```

```css
.tt1 img {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.swiper-slide img {
  width: 225px;
  height: 400px;
}
.ee2 .swiper-slide:first-child img {
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tt1"></div>
<div class="ss1">...</div>
<div class="ee1">
  <div class="ee2">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/225x400">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/225x400">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/225x400">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

***As a side note***: I recommend removing these inline-style css properties and using them in an external css file.

*Replace style attribute:*

```
style="width: 225px; height: 400px;"
```

*With:*

```
.ee2 .swiper-slide img {
  width: 225px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

(In an External CSS file)

Comment: You can remove style of image ?

Comment: Yes, I will suggest setting width and height in an external css file rather than using inline-style. Will edit.